# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, mysql, excel

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hello";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

echo "connected";

use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

// Include Spout library 
include ('spout-2.4.3\src\Spout\Autoloader\autoload.php');

// check file name is not empty
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {

    // Get File extension eg. 'xlsx' to check file is excel sheet
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    // check file has extension xlsx, xls and also check 
    // file is not empty
   if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls') 
           && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {

        // Temporary file name
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

        // Read excel file by using ReadFactory object.
        $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

        // Open file
        $reader->open($inputFileName);
        $count = 1;
        $rows = array(); 

        // Number of sheet in excel file
        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {

            // Number of Rows in Excel sheet
            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

                // It reads data after header. In the my excel sheet, 
                // header is in the first row. 
                if ($count> 1){

                $newDate = $row[4]-> format('d/m/Y');   

                $result=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO stud VALUES                         ('NULL','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$newDate','$row[5]','$row[6]','$row[7]')");

                }
                $count++;
            }


        }

        // Close excel file
        $reader->close();

    } else {

        echo "Please Select Valid Excel File";
    }

} else {

    echo "Please Select Excel File";

}
?>
```

This is the php script am used to import excel file to mysql database ,i got an error while inserting date from excel to mysql table.

```
$newDate = $row[4]-> format('d/m/Y');   
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO stud VALUES           ('NULL','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$newDate','$row[5]','$row[6]','$row[7]')");
```

I try to format the row[4] ,but it shows "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string"  error.Any solution?

Excel file:
[click to view excel which am working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pki.jpg)

Comment: You are calling `format` method on string (not on `DateTime` object) which is causing issue. You need to create an object of `DateTime` and then call `format` on that object. Please share some sample entries of excel, I need to see the format of date into it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman It's a different issue and so the question need to be updated.

Comment: You'll also want to use a proper `DATE` column and ISO-8601 standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format for your dates. These can be indexed, sorted, and aren't ambiguous like `d/m/y` can be, as `m/d/y` looks very similar.

Comment: Problem solved . i use PHPExcel library for importing excel to mysql ,instead of these codes..any way thanks for helping .

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$newDate = $row[4]-> format('d/m/Y');
```

To

```
`
```

```
if(!empty($row[4])){
    $_newDate = new DateTime($row[4]);
}else{
    $_newDate = new DateTime();
}
$newDate = $_newDate->format('d/m/Y');
```

`
Because $row[4] is string not object Date time.

Comment: It shows syntax error on this line: $newDate = new DateTime($row[4])->format('d/m/Y');

Comment: $row[4] data is not fomat date time . Can you var_dump this and give me.

Comment: object(DateTime)#12 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "1995-05-25 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } string(10) "25/06/1889" string(0) ""

Comment: There is another error by using your edited post:                                   Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exelwork\sss\uploadExcel.php:56 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\exelwork\sss\uploadExcel.php(56): DateTime->__construct(Object(DateTime)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\exelwork\sss\uploadExcel.php on line 56

Comment: Can you give me exel file ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$newDate = $row[4]-> format('d/m/Y');
```

to

```
$newDate = new DateTime($row[4])->format('d/m/Y');
```

You were calling `format` method on string.

Comment: The query shows syntax error ,i cant find out the reason.

Comment: @Shinoypb that's a different issue. include it in question as well.

Answer (score 0):

NEW CODE

```
<!doctype>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    //disply db table in php page
    mysqli_select_db($conn,'demo_data');


    require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";

            $tmpfname = "test.xlsx";
            $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
            $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
            $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
            $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

            //echo "<table>";
            for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
                // echo "<tr><td>";
                 $a= $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
                // echo "</td><td>";
                 $b= $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
                 $c= $worksheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getFormattedValue();
                 echo $a." ".$b." ".$c." ";
                $timestamp = strtotime($c);
    $e = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp );
    //echo $e;
                // echo "</td><tr>";
                $query="INSERT INTO excel_data VALUES('NULL','$a','$b','$e') ";
                $check=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                if($check)
                {
                    echo "ok";
                    }
                    else {
                        "no data insertion";
                    }

            }
            //echo "</table>";  
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I used PHPExcel library for importing excel files to mysql.The PHPExcel library simply handle the date conversion problem while importing to mysql.
Thanks ....